# How a Delegate or an Event Handler can return bool type?

Tags: asp.net, windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, windows-phone-7.1

I am using a web service to call my method,and my that method returns a Boolean.And Here is my code in a cs file.

```
`obj = new GBService.PreGroupbookSreviceSoapClient();
 obj.AddBasicInfoCompleted +=new EventHandler<GBService.AddBasicInfoCompletedEventArgs>(obj_AddBasicInfoCompleted);`
```

Now the problem is that this "**obj_AddBasicInfoCompleted**" method created by VS2010 returns by default void type.I want in this place a Boole type method to be generated.
When I change the method type by void to Boolean or bool , the VS2010 Gives an error on the above mention line saying "**bool obj_AddBasicInfoCompleted(object sender, GBService.AddBasicInfoCompletedEventArgs e) has the wrong return type.**"

I dont know how to do that .Plz help me thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 2):

> I want in this place a Boole type method to be generated.

Then you'd need to change the delegate type used... because [`EventHandler<TEventArgs>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x.aspx) *doesn't* return a value.

You haven't really said *why* you want to do this, but in general if you're trying to work against the normal conventions of .NET, you should reconsider your design. In particular, if you're trying to use standard components which expect a `EventHandler<TEventArgs>` and expose events using it, how would you expect them to *use* a return value?

Comment: I want to do this to check whether this method has done adding the basic info in DB and "  **`obj.AddBasicInfoAsync(username, fullname, gender, Encrypted_password, DOB, Email, mobile);`**" Has done working perfectly or not?

Comment: But where would you expect to get the return value from? Perhaps you need a void method to act as an event handler, which can *call* a `bool` method if that's useful.

Comment: I expect the bool returning from the method or Event that is created by VS2010.I am uploading the screen shot which might give u a lill good understanging wht i am trying to do!!
![enter image description here][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/wzCr0.png

Answer (score 0):

An event, by its nature, is typically used in a circumstance where getting a return value is really (almost) not meaningful, so it makes me question how you've designed something that is wanting it. Not inherently saying its wrong, its just very different and does tend to go against the grain of how the event "system" is intended to work.

The only way you're really going to get around this is to declare your own custom event handler delegate that returns your boolean value, then go through some gymnastics to get that value out wherever you're wanting it. VS 2010 isn't just arbitrarily returning a void, but abiding by the default EventHandler delegate signature - which returns a void.

If you could share why you're wanting to do this, perhaps we could help with a somewhat improved design that might mitigate the need to accomplish this particular objective.

Comment: **An event, by its nature, is typically used in a circumstance where getting a return value is really (almost) not meaningful,** how is this possible? What if I need some value back when some event has been performed? So you cannot say that, and I am not going against the grain,it just become a scenario in which I have to do this. And could you please be more kind to provide some details or links to the custom event handler Delegates????

Comment: The point is that you have designed a scenario where you want a value back from an event. The point Jon Skeet and I are, each, trying to make is that what you are doing is, as a matter of fact, against the design grain for the way .NET handles events. I can't show you custom event handler delegates because *you* have to write them. The .NET model, where events do not return values, provides for the *default* EventHandler delegate, that does not return a value. That's why Jon and I both offered that perhaps a better architecture/design was possible.

Comment: I expect the bool returning from the method or Event that is created by VS2010.I am uploading the screen shot which might give u a lill good understanging wht i am trying to do!!
![enter image description here][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/wzCr0.png

Comment: I would, respectfully, suggest that when you are soliciting help from others that a somewhat less combative attitude would be more appropriate. I certainly don't know all the .NET in the world, but I can recognize a scenario that looks like a problem from the design side, and this might be one. But what sounds like an angry, defensive reply doesn't exactly encourage others to help. Good luck in your project.

Comment: Sir ...now by looking at the picture I uploaded,you might get the point what i want...Thanks

Comment: No i never said that in any angry or bad manner.I really respect the people here on this site.Its a great platform ,by the way my native language is not english thats why it might sounded bad to you. :)